# Manage settings bundle with reference to device

Tags: ios, iphone, settings.bundle, touch-id

I have touch id functionality in my application. I have created a option in settings bundle to enable and disable the touch id. The problem is I am able to see the touch id settings in the device s which does not support touch id (iPhone 5, iPhone 4s).

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the standard settings bundle provides very little flexibility. There is no way to selectively show options.

You would be better off not using the settings bundle and add your own settings page in your app. Then you can customize as needed.

I've never used it myself, but the [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit) on github seems popular.